# Client can connect and send message to Ratchet but can't receive from server

Tags: php, web-services, apache2, debian, ratchet

i have a web application which communicates with server via websockets. I am using Ratchet as a websockets server.
On localhost i'm using `XAMPP (Apache 2.4.10 and PHP 5.6.3)` and everything works beautifuly. On my VPS i'm running Debian 8, Apache 2.4.10, PHP 5.6.7 and i have a problem with server to client communication. Ratchet is running at port 8080.

Clients can succesfuly connects to Ratchet (via `ws://ipOfServer:8080`) and send him a message (ratchet will print it), but when Ratchet sends message to client, nothing arrived at client.

I've tried enable Apache module mod_proxy_wstunnel and add `ProxyPass "/wsc/" "ws://ipOfServer:8080"` to my domain config. Clients now connects to Ratchet via ws://ipOfServer/wsc, and its the same story as without using proxy.

Can somebody please help me, how to get running it? Thakns

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your Ratchet Server class